# How does one use glide to download an image into a drawable?

Tags: android, android-glide

I have learning Image Slider Using ViewPager. For that, I want the images to be dynamic. Glide is easy but I think I am not using it properly. 
Here's what I am trying to do.

```
//Initialize by default Images
private static final Integer[] IMAGES = {R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2};

// Load images into Drawables using Glide 
        Glide.with(this)
                .load("https://google.com/someImage1.jpg")
                  .error(R.drawable.image1)
                  .into(R.drawable.image1);
        Glide.with(this)
                .load("https://google.com/someImage2.jpg")
                  .error(R.drawable.image2)
                  .into(R.drawable.image2);

// Set Again
 IMAGES[0]= R.drawable.image1;
 IMAGES[1]= R.drawable.image2;
```

But `.into(java.lang.Integer`) is not defined and I know that. But I want something that would solve my problem. I have slider view. In that I need to pass the Images as drawables or something like that. Image loading would be carried by Adapter. I can't load directly as far as I know.  Is there any way to load glide images in `drawable`.

Also what is the best way to catch or store the images locally, so that if there is no internet connection, still the slider works smoothly.

Here is my Adapater

```
public class MainPageSlideImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Integer> IMAGES;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;


    public MainPageSlideImageAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Integer> IMAGES) {
        this.context = context;
        this.IMAGES=IMAGES;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return IMAGES.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_page_slidingimages, view, false);

        assert imageLayout != null;
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.image);

        imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES.get(position));
        view.addView(imageLayout, 0);

        return imageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: When you get an error that a method is not defined, always check the documentation. The `R.drawable` references are integers. The documentation clearly shows an ImageView is loaded into

Comment: Thanks. I do understand and did read documentation. Please read the details that I have added.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of storing the image in memory, store the address instead.

```
private static final String[] IMAGES = {"https://google.com/someImage1.jpg", "https://google.com/someImage2.jpg"};
```

Then load the image when you `instantiateItem`

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
    View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_page_slidingimages, view, false);
    assert imageLayout != null;
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
    Glide.with(context)
         .load(IMAGES.get(position))
         .error(R.drawable.image1)
         .into(imageView);    
    view.addView(imageLayout, 0);    
    return imageLayout;
}
```

Also, glide provides memory and disk caching. This means it should be able to show images even  if there is no internet.

Comment: I understand that. But I have slider view. In that I need to pass the Images as drawables or something like that. Image loading would be carried by Adapter. I can't load directly as far as I know.

Comment: Sure. Please look at the adapater's constructor where I am working with integers of images.

Comment: @ArewegoodQ I have updated my answer. Also, `Drawable` cannot be changed after compiled.

Comment: Yeah. I understood. Your answer is pretty close to what I wanted. Of course, what I wanted is impossible :D Hence Accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

you must provide the view in `.into()` please view the sample

sample layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

**Update**

```
 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_page_slidingimages, view, false);

        assert imageLayout != null;
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.image);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(IMAGES.get(position))
                  .error(R.drawable.image2)
                  .into(imageView);
        //imageView.setImageResource();
        view.addView(imageLayout, 0);

        return imageLayout;
    }
```

Comment: I understand that. But I have slider view. In that I need to pass the Images as drawables or something like that. Image loading would be carried by Adapter. I can't load directly as far as I know.

Comment: @ArewegoodQ updated my answer from your above code i believe your sending array of images to the adapter so i am getting the image from the array and loading it into the image view with glide please check if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

`imageView.setImageResource` simply needs replaced with a Glide call.

Or use an ArrayAdapter of Strings for Urls that you want to download. I don't think you can "overwrite" a drawable from Glide